# Double click JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, tablecelleditor

The cells in my JTable become editable only on the second click. When I debugged I noticed that on the second click the mouse released event is not fired. I saw a lot of answers for this problem with create a setSingleClick(1)... but it doesn't to work. I think that if i can get that second mouseReleased event to get fire i might be able to make it work. Does anybody has any sugestions?

```
table.addMouseListener(new TableMouseListener()) ;
class TableMouseListener extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         System.out.println("mousePressed");
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseClicked"); 
        }
       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
          System.out.println("mouseReleased");
       }
}
```

Comment: parameter for numbers of click for TableCellEditor is settable, default is two click

Comment: Does getClickCount() on the MouseEvent not give you the info you need?

Comment: I think that getClickCount() returns a classic double click. In my case, i can click wait for a while and only if i click again the cell becomes editable

Comment: Maybe something like "((DefaultCellEditor)table.getCellEditor()).setClickCountToStart(1)" then?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
container_table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
                //Double clicked
            }
        }
    });
```

This way, you know that the 'container_table' has been clicked twice, and then you can get the selected row, and make things with it.

Hope it helps.